# Get all result options from the table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, algorithm

I have the following table:

```
key | val
----------
aaa | 1
aaa | 2
aaa | 3
bbb | x
bbb | y
bbb | z
ccc | on
ccc | off
```

And I need to write a list of all the keys options with their value.

Meaning, the output shold be:

```
aaa | 1 | bbb | x | ccc | on
aaa | 1 | bbb | x | ccc | off
aaa | 1 | bbb | y | ccc | on
aaa | 1 | bbb | y | ccc | off
aaa | 1 | bbb | z | ccc | on
aaa | 1 | bbb | z | ccc | off
aaa | 2 | bbb | x | ccc | on
aaa | 2 | bbb | x | ccc | off
aaa | 2 | bbb | y | ccc | on
aaa | 2 | bbb | y | ccc | off
aaa | 2 | bbb | z | ccc | on
aaa | 2 | bbb | z | ccc | off
aaa | 3 | bbb | x | ccc | on
aaa | 3 | bbb | x | ccc | off
aaa | 3 | bbb | y | ccc | on
aaa | 3 | bbb | y | ccc | off
aaa | 3 | bbb | z | ccc | on
aaa | 3 | bbb | z | ccc | off
```

But I don't know the keys and the values, that can change everytime...

Can anyone help me think of a good algorithm to do it?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: sql server. 
but i dont care if the answer will be in c# javascript sql server or oracle or any language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive algorithm :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("key", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("val", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"aaa","1"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"aaa","2"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"aaa","3"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"bbb","x"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"bbb","y"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"bbb","z"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"ccc","on"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"ccc","off"});

            Data.data = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("key"))
                .Select(x => new Data()
                {
                    key = x.Key,
                    values = x.Select(y => y.Field<string>("val")).ToList()
                }).ToList();

            Data.Print(0, new List<string>());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public static List<Data> data = null;
        public string key { get; set; }
        public List<string> values { get; set; }

        public static void Print(int level, List<string> output)
        {
            if (level == data.Count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", output));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(string _value in data[level].values)
                {
                    List<string> newOutput = new List<string>();
                    newOutput.AddRange(output);
                    newOutput.Add(data[level].key);
                    newOutput.Add(_value);
                    Print(level + 1, newOutput);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Code gives exactly results expected when tested.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the keys (as in your example), then you can just an explicit `cross join`:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from (select t.* from t where key = 'a') a cross join
     (select t.* from t where key = 'b') b cross join
     (select t.* from t where key = 'c') c;
```

If you do not know all the keys, then you will need to generate the query using dynamic SQL.

Comment: i dont know the keys and the values, that can change everytime...  thanks any way :)